# Display certain field values of submissions from multiple webforms in one view

Tags: views, webforms

I have two separate webforms, and I want to be able to display all submissions from both webforms that have the same value of a specific field. I also want different fields to be displayed based on what form they're coming from.

For example, both webforms have a field called area.
I would like to display the submissions of both these webforms if they both have area set to the same value. Amongst these submissions, if they're from form 1, I want to display the values for field1,field2,and field3 in the view. If they're from form2, I want to display the values for field4,field5, and field6 in the view.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a view?

Comment: Is this 7 or 8? And are you using the webform module? Also by answers what do you mean? A list of all the submissions?

Comment: Drupal 7, yes I am using the webform module. I'm sorry not answers but Webform submission data: Value for two different webform nodes.

Comment: Do you mean the values of every submission of the two webforms?

Comment: Not every value but most

Comment: Do you mean the most recent submissions?

Comment: No. I have a webform with one field being "Areas", I am filtering the webform by the different "Areas" into their own specific view. I want to filter an additional webform with the same "Areas" into the same view. I added a new block in the view and filitered using the specific "Area" and webform node but the results don't show.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show the submissions of each webform that have the same value for 'Areas'?

Comment: Yes. But I want to be able to pull specific values, not all of them

Comment: So as an example, you want to be able to pull 'field 1', 'field 3', and 'field 7' of the submissions from webform 1 and webform 2 that have 'area' set to 'area1'?

Comment: I want to be able to pull 'field 1', 'field 3', and 'field 7' of the submissions from webform 1 and 'field 2', 'field 3', and field 5' of the submissions from webform 2 while both webforms have 'area' set to 'area1'

Comment: I'm not sure how to accomplish this in drupal 7 inside a view, but I have edited your question for clarity so hopefully it will get more help and attention. Edit your question again if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2497183

> Views cannot display information from more than one webform at a time
>   **unless the webforms share the same components**.
>
> One solution would be to add order# as a hidden field so that all
>   webforms have a component by this field key. I haven't tried having
>   mixed component types for with the same field key, but I suspect it
>   will work, at least with some view configurations

You may wind up having to create a template for a module to get the report you are looking for.

Drupal answers actually already has a post on this: 
[Multiple Webforms in one View](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101614/multiple-webforms-in-one-view)